# Prime faces Custom Data table inside Treetable(Matser details data)

Tags: java, user-interface, jsf, primefaces, icefaces

I need custom data-table(p:datatable with different columns than parent table columns) inside tree-table. Below is image

[image]

I tried tree-table but in my case child row should be data-table with column headers and rows different than parent table.Also child table should have checkbox selection.

I there any JSF variant other than prime faces having ready made component mentioned as above to display master details relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a data table with [expansion](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml) and use a child data table in the expansion. From the showcase:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Expand rows to see detailed information
    </f:facet>
    <p:column style="width:16px">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:rowExpansion>
        <!-- Add your child data table here -->
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```